# Wav Secure Streaming ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, flash

So my problem is : I have a website, a file sharing kind of website, where users can upload(to server), download(from server) files.Everything nice and cool but now a have a new requirement. For 'wav' files i must provide to the users the possibility of listening the file directly into the browser but without the possibility to download file(not directly) on their computers. So first my attention headed to SILVERLIGHT and control mediaelement (Silverlight